# SQL statement is good but data is not being submitted node / mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, api

(I know there's similar questions, but none align with my problem, and I've tried everything except the right solution)

Hello, so I'm trying to store an email, latitude and longitude to a table in mysql using node. The data I have is good, as I log it after I get the request (it shows my proper logged in email, shows my proper lat and longitude), but the query comes back undefined.

what data types should I make lat and long? I've tried decimal(9,6) and float, and neither work.

the error I'm getting from my console is a parse error, 42000
it also shows the proper values being sent to the database in the query...

Here's my query:

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO testspot2 (email, lat, long) VALUES (?,?,?)", [email,lat,long], (err, result) => {
        console.log("query res", result);
        if (err) {
            return res.send({ err: err });
            //   res.sendStatus(500);
        }
         if (result.length < 0) {
                console.log("query result sucess",result);
                return res.send({
                    // status: "success",
                    data: "Success"
                });
              
            } else {
                console.log("query result fail?", result);
                return res.send({
                    errormessage: "Failed to save location.",
                    status: "fail"

                });
                
            }
            return;
    });
```

Comment: enable the general log in the data base and see what mysql actually receives.and then disable it again

Comment: @nbk i  had no idea that was a thing, I'll try to figure that out. thanks.

Comment: @nbk according to my database host, they aren't able to do it.

Comment: did you test it on a local computer where you have access to all, you couls also try to insert it with your values via console or whatever you have and see if there is a problem there

Answer (score 0):

naming one of my columns "long" was terrible practice but I didn't think it would cause a problem. Renaming it to longitude (both in my DB and my query) fixed it.